# Using the Identity Web API in .NET Core with Angular and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement a user admin panel that allows admin users to see roles related to the current application user as well as all other users and the roles assigned to them.

The purpose of this functionality is to allow admin users to add, edit, and delete roles and users. I have included a link to functionality similar to what I am needing but this was done in ASP.NET Core.

I have been looking for days for something that I could use to help me get started on this using Angular and Typescript but haven't been able to find much of anything or nothing. If anyone can give me some hints to get started or an article to get me started it would be greatly appreciated.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36804.asp-net-core-mvc-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-with-asp-net-core-identity.aspx

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: The article you linked already have the key pieces you need. Very simple. Basically all you need to do is convert the Controller portion to ApiController and return a JSON response. Then you just build your angular app to display the data with the basic CRUD.